# getting sigarbt error while copying NSString to NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

```
PlistReader *pList = [[PlistReader alloc] init];
    [pList initWithFileName:@"CountryDetails"];
    CountryClass *objcountry =(CountryClass*) [pList getCountryInfoById:countryId];
    CCSprite *flag = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:objcountry.ImageUrl];
    flag.position = ccp(200, 265);
    flag.scale = .255;
    NSString *tempdata = objcountry.ShortDetail;//error line sigabrt
    TextViewTopFlagData = [[UITextView alloc]init];
    TextViewTopFlagData.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"this is pakistan"];//countryInfo.ShortDetail;
    TextViewTopFlagData.frame = CGRectMake(260,17, 105, 75);
    TextViewTopFlagData.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [TextViewTopFlagData setEditable:NO];
```

hi i am getting error sigabrt on line which i mention it objcountry.ShortDetail is also NSString type so why it is getting error here sigabrt can any one help

when i put the NSString *tempdata = objcountry.ShortDetail;//error line sigabrt before the sprite line it got no error but when i put back after the sprite line it again got that error so can any one explain me that

here is the countryClass structer

//CountryClass.h

```
//
//  CountryClass.h
//  NationalAntemsAndFlags
//
//  Created by mac on 12/17/11.
//  Copyright (c) 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CountryClass : NSObject
{
    NSString *Name ;
    NSString *ImageUrl;
    NSString *AnthemUrl;
    NSString *ShortDetail;
    NSString *completeDetails;
    int LocationX ;
    int LocationY ;


}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet NSString *Name;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet NSString *ImageUrl;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet NSString *AnthemUrl;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet NSString *ShortDetail;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet NSString *completeDetails;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet int LocationY;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet int LocationX;




@end
```

//countryClass.m

```
//
//  CountryClass.m
//  NationalAntemsAndFlags
//
//  Created by mac on 12/17/11.
//  Copyright (c) 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "CountryClass.h"

@implementation CountryClass

@synthesize Name,ImageUrl,AnthemUrl,ShortDetail,completeDetails,LocationX,LocationY;

@end
```

this is the countryClass structure and i did tried to [countryInfo retain] but nothing happend

Comment: can you show us -(CountryClass*)getCountryInfoById: and CountryClass.h?

Comment: Maybe the loading of the sprite causes your autorelease pool to empty.  Try [objcountry retain]; before CCSprite *flag... and [objcountry release] after NSString * tempdata...   If that doesn't work, you will need to show a little more code and the debugger output on crash

Comment: i provide the class check it now

Answer (score 2):

`objcountry` is not an actual instance of a `CountryClass`, it's some other type of object (whatever `[pList getCountryInfoById:country]` returns).  If it's not obvious from the code what type of object it is, try printing it out with `NSLog(@"objcountry is a %@", [objcountry class]);`.

The expression `objcountry.ShortDetail` is syntactic sugar for the property accessor method `[objcountry ShortDetail]`.  When the runtime tries to send the message `ShortDetail` to the obejct but the object doesn't respond to that message, the dreaded `NSInvalidArgumentException` gets thrown with the message "unrecognized selector sent to class" (this should get printed to the debug console).  If nobody catches that exception (as is often the case), the runtime responds by calling the [`abort(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/abort) method, which terminates the application with the `SIGABRT` signal.

Comment: thanks for reply but when i put the NSString *tempdata = objcountry.ShortDetail;//error line sigabrt
 before the sprite line it got no error but when i put back after the sprite line it again got that error so can you explain me that